# r? . the meaning of in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a little program that does

```
var lineArray = lines.split("\r?\n")
```

Before it was

```
var lineArray = lines.split("\n")
```

which did not work. I found the answer obviously (as in the correction I need to make) but I can't for the life of me find why this happened.

The file it was doing this for was a csv,
    shoot, plucky
    darn, beans

Answer (score 16):

This has nothing to do with scala. The is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) question. `?` in regex means match zero or one occurrences. So this matches `\r\n` or `\n`.

Comment: also note that ? is inherently greedy. it always tries to match the one occurrence, and if that fails it backtracks.

Comment: Okay it seems the answer is to look into regular expressions! 

Thanks!

Comment: Sean is there a better way I can check into? If no response I'll gladly read up on regex stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This is looking for either `\n` or `\r\n` which will identify line breaks on windows machines as well as non windows machines.